# better complexity for reading data (string to integer represntation)

Tags: java, string, complexity-theory

I have to read a text file, line by line, and in each line to read all the k-length strings, convert them into integer representation, and  keep them in hash-map.

which of the following will give better running time result?

first option:

1. converting the whole line to integer representation
2. run over the line in k-length windows and read the data

second option:

1. run over the string line in k-length window
2. for each substring - convert it into integer representation

I think the first option is better, but I want to be sure

Comment: Test it with System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: How do you convert lines to "integer representation"?

Comment: its only four letters, so each of them gets binary number (00/01/10/11)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to be sure is verifying it yourself. Implementing both your options and writing test cases measuring the performance with a significantly large input will enable you to find the better option.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to make you algorithm more efficient is to reuse to save the calculation. For a string `S=S[0]S[1]S[2]...S[n-1]`, you want to get all the integer values for each k-length substring, a better way is to reuse. That is if we have known the integer value of S[0]S[1]...S[k-1], suppose it is V1, then you want to calculate `S[1]S[2]...S[k]`, an efficient way to get the value by `V2=(V1-10^k*(S[0]-'0'))*10 + (S[k]-'0')`.

Of course, you can also optimize I/O operations.